# Rust FFI passing trait object as context to call callbacks on

Tags: c, rust, ffi

Okay, I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. C calls into rust
2. rust calls back into c and registers a callback on a user defined trait object
3. c calls into rust with the context
4. rust calls the callback on the context (trait object)

I've been playing around with it quite a bit. I got quite far, but still not quite there.

The C bit:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *global_ctx;

void c_function(void* ctx) {
    printf("Called c_function\n");
    global_ctx = ctx;
}

int main(void) {
    void *thing = dlopen("thing/target/debug/libthing.dylib", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (!thing) {
        printf("error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    void (*rust_function)(void) = dlsym(thing, "rust_function");
    void (*rust_cb)(void*) = dlsym(thing, "rust_cb");
    printf("rust_function = %p\n", rust_function);
    rust_function();

    rust_cb(global_ctx);
}
```

The rust bit:

```
extern crate libc;


pub trait Foo {
    fn callback(&self);
}

extern {
    fn c_function(context: *mut libc::c_void);
}

pub struct MyFoo;
impl Foo for MyFoo {
    fn callback(&self) {
        println!("callback on trait");
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_cb(context: *mut Foo) {
    unsafe {
        let cb:Box<Foo> = Box::from_raw(context);
        cb.callback();
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_function() {
    println!("Called rust_function");
    let tmp = Box::new(MyFoo);
    unsafe {
        c_function(Box::into_raw(tmp) as *const Foo as *mut libc::c_void);
    }
}
```

The issue:

- My program segfaults when I try to call "callback" on the trait object in "rust_cb"

One Solution:
 - Change the function signature of "rust_cb" to

```
pub extern fn rust_cb(context: *mut MyFoo)
```

but that's not what I want, as I'm trying to create a safe wrapper that only knows the trait of the listener

Any help appreciated

PS: my assumption is that it segfaults, because the compiler doesn't know the offset of callback on the trait Foo, it needs the actual object to determine where it is. but then i have no idea how to work around that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, if you need to represent the `Foo` as a `void *`, you can use this:

```
extern crate libc;

pub trait Foo {
    fn callback(&self);
}

extern {
    fn c_function(context: *mut libc::c_void);
}

pub struct MyFoo;
impl Foo for MyFoo {
    fn callback(&self) {
        println!("callback on trait");
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_cb(context: *mut Box<Foo>) {
    unsafe {
        let cb: Box<Box<Foo>> = Box::from_raw(context);
        cb.callback();
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_function() {
    println!("Called rust_function");
    let tmp: Box<Box<Foo>> = Box::new(Box::new(MyFoo));
    unsafe {
        c_function(Box::into_raw(tmp) as *mut Box<Foo> as *mut libc::c_void);
    }
}
```

I think you may be misunderstanding what a trait object is. A trait object is a type that is the size of two pointers (so, 128 bits on a 64-bit system). In this example, `Foo` is not a trait object, it is a dynamically sized type (i.e. a type which has a variable size, such as `str`). `Box<Foo>` is a trait object. `Box<Box<Foo>>` is neither a trait object or a dynamically sized type, it is a type that has the same size as a pointer, which is why we need to use it here since we want to convert it into a `void *`.

I call it "leaking" because when you call `Box::into_raw`, you are leaking the memory of whatever is in the box, which means that that you are responsible for making sure the destructor (the `Drop` implementation) gets called.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!
I think I understand it now. Don't know why, but I'm finding it quite hard to get my head around all that stuff coming from C :(

Comment: `rust_function` doesn't have to be pub extern, or does it?

Answer (score 4):

Rust trait objects such as `Box<Foo>` are double the size of a normal pointer, so you can't use `void *` to represent them. See [`std::raw::TraitObject`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html) for more information. Here is a working version of your code:

program.c:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct rs_trait_obj {
    void *data;
    void *vtable;
};

struct rs_trait_obj global_ctx;

void c_function(struct rs_trait_obj ctx) {
    printf("Called c_function\n");
    global_ctx = ctx;
}

int main(void) {
    void *thing = dlopen("thing/target/debug/libthing.dylib", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if (!thing) {
        printf("error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return 1;
    }
    void (*rust_function)(void) = dlsym(thing, "rust_function");
    void (*rust_cb)(struct rs_trait_obj) = dlsym(thing, "rust_cb");
    printf("rust_function = %p\n", rust_function);
    rust_function();

  rust_cb(global_ctx);
}
```

lib.rs:

```
#![feature(raw)]

extern crate libc;

use std::raw::TraitObject;
use std::mem;

pub trait Foo {
    fn callback(&self);
}

extern {
    fn c_function(context: TraitObject);
}

pub struct MyFoo;
impl Foo for MyFoo {
    fn callback(&self) {
        println!("callback on trait");
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_cb(context: TraitObject) {
    unsafe {
        let cb: Box<Foo> = mem::transmute(context);
        cb.callback();
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_function() {
    println!("Called rust_function");
    let tmp: Box<Foo> = Box::new(MyFoo);
    unsafe {
        c_function(mem::transmute(tmp));
    }
}
```

This will only work on nightly rustc (because of the `#![feature(raw)]`) and will also give a warning because `TraitObject` isn't FFI-safe. If you want something that will work on stable, you can define some struct of an appropriate size like this and use it instead of `TraitObject`:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct FFITraitObject {
    data: usize,
    vtable: usize,
}
```

Another option, of course, would just be to use `Box<Foo>` in place of `TraitObject`, but then you would still get a warning:

```
extern crate libc;

pub trait Foo {
    fn callback(&self);
}

extern {
    fn c_function(context: Box<Foo>);
}

pub struct MyFoo;
impl Foo for MyFoo {
    fn callback(&self) {
        println!("callback on trait");
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_cb(context: Box<Foo>) {
    context.callback();
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_function() {
    println!("Called rust_function");
    let tmp: Box<Foo> = Box::new(MyFoo);
    unsafe {
        c_function(tmp);
    }
}
```

If you really want to use a `void *`, you could consider leaking the `TraitObject` as well as the `MyFoo` and use two levels of indirection.

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand how to get it working with the c_void and how to "leak" the TraitObject. 
I can't really/don't want to change the C side - and would wanna use as little overhead/indirection as possible. Maybe what I want is not easily achievable. (PS: I can pass extra arguments into the real C function, so maybe I can pass the type down to rust? )