# Is there any way to convert Box<Box<Foo + Send>> to Box<Box<Foo>>?

Tags: rust

Consider such code:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

fn consume_func(b: Box<Box<Foo>>) {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn produce_func() -> Box<Box<Foo + Send>> {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn main() {
    let b = produce_func();
    consume_func(b);
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:24:18
   |
24 |     consume_func(b);
   |                  ^ expected trait `Foo`, found trait `Foo + std::marker::Send`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::boxed::Box<std::boxed::Box<Foo + 'static>>`
              found type `std::boxed::Box<std::boxed::Box<Foo + std::marker::Send>>`
```

The double `Box` is [a way to give a C library a `void *` pointer from `Box<Trait>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33929079/155423). Because of fat pointers, I can not convert `Box<Foo>` to `void *`.

I can not change `consume_func`, and I'd prefer to not use `unsafe` or additional allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you've stated you cannot change `consume_func`, others with similar issues can change it to accept a generic:

```
fn consume_func<F: Foo + ?Sized>(b: Box<Box<F>>) {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it: dereference `b` ("un-boxing" it to a `Box<Foo + Send>`), then wrap it up immediately in another `Box<T>`, allowing the compiler to infer the correct `T` (in this case `Box<Foo>`).

```
consume_func(Box::new(*b));
```

This works because `Box<Foo + Send>` can be automatically coerced to `Box<Foo>`, but `Box<Box<Foo + Send>>` cannot be coerced to `Box<Box<Foo>>`.